# I'm trying to make a login page using Semantic UI but it won't align to the center

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

So I'm trying to make a login page with Semantic UI, but the results is that the column doesn't aligned to the center, it fills the whole page instead.
I have tried to link everything in the dist folder.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8UKJ.png) is how it looks.

This is the code:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="semantic/dist/semantic.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ui middle aligned center aligned grid">
        <div class="column">
          <h2 class="ui teal image header">
            <div class="content">
              Form
            </div>
          </h2>
          <form class="ui large form">
            <div class="ui stacked segment">
              <div class="field">
                <div class="ui left icon input">
                  <i class="user icon"></i>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="field">
                <div class="ui left icon input">
                  <i class="user icon"></i>
                  <input type="number" placeholder="Phone Number">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="field">
                <div class="ui left icon input">
                  <i class="user icon"></i>
                  <input type="email" placeholder="Email Adress">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="field">
                <div class="ui left icon input">
                  <i class="lock icon"></i>
                  <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="ui fluid large teal submit button">Login</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="semantic/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Muhammad, what you need is a flexbox in css. It will solve this problem and several others in the future. Google it on YouTube with live examples. I can't write you right now an exact code but if won't solve it alone or no one else will reply you, I will write you exact code. I write from a smartphone.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your CSS:

```
.column {
  max-width: 25%;
}
```

or add it inline to your `column` like this this:

`<div class="column" style="max-width: 25%;">`